# Repeatedly adding image size before the file extention

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem and I can't seem to find the reason for the issue I'm a little new to both JavaScript and jQuery.

but by using the below and then resize the page instead of simply adding the size of the image to the image src is is added repeatedly e.g responsive_Course_2_2_large_large_large_large_large_large.png instead of Responsive_Course_2_2_large.png

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    if ($(window).width() < 600) {

        if (ImageSize != 'stand') {
            $.each(imgIds, function (index, value) {
                Image_src = $('#' + value).attr('src');
                Image = Image_src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i, '$1');
                $('#' + value).attr('src', Image);
                $('#' + value).attr("ImageSize", 'stand');
            });
            $('#PageContentRow').attr('style', 'background-image:Url(../img/' + pageID + '_back.png)');
        }
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 960 && $(window).width() < 1280) {
        if (ImageSize != 'large') {
            $.each(imgIds, function (index, value) {
                Image_src = $('#' + value).attr('src');
                ImageLarge = Image_src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i, '_large$1');
                $('#' + value).attr('src', ImageLarge);
                $('#' + value).attr("ImageSize", 'large');
            });
            $('#PageContentRow').attr('style', 'background-image:Url(../img/' + pageID + '_back_Large.png)');
        }
    }
   else {
        $.each(imgIds, function (index, value) {
            Image_src = $('#' + value).attr('src');
            Image = Image_src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i, '$1');
            $('#' + value).attr('src', Image);
            $('#' + value).attr("ImageSize", 'stand');
        });
        $('#PageContentRow').attr('style', 'background-image:Url(../img/' + pageID + '_back.png)');
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't set the "style" like that: use `.css("background-image", "whatever");` - also to set the "src" use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: Also: doing this in a "resize" handler is really not going to work out ... the "resize" event is fired **a lot** as the user resizes; many times a second.  Trying to do all that work in the handler directly will have terrible performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly alternative approach, but have you considered instead setting a class on the `body` when the window is resized, and then having multiple `CSS` classes for the appropriate sizes? I think it would be slightly neater, and would also mean the `JavaScript` and `CSS` are less-tightly coupled together. It would also mean that you could use the size to determine other aspects of elements on the page.

1. Page resize
2. Width is less than 600

   - Set the body class to `small`
3. Width is between 960 and 1280

   - Set the body class to `medium`
4. Width is greater than 1280

   - Set the body class to `large`

This would then mean that within your `CSS` you could do:

```
body.small #PageContentRow
{
    background-image: url('/my-image_small.png');
}
body.medium #PageContentRow
{
    background-image: url('/my-image_medium.png');
}
body.large #PageContentRow
{
    background-image: url('/my-image_large.png');
}
```

Comment: ... and CSS media queries could make it even better.

Comment: Sorry this will not work as this would me the end user would have to download all images.

Comment: The original approach will also require the user download 3 images upon window resizing.

Comment: but this is only if they resize if a mobile user was to come to the page they would not want to download all tree images.

Answer (score 0):

Because you keep adding it to the image.

Below you are chopping off the file extension and adding _large to it.

```
ImageLarge = Image_src.replace(/(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i, '_large$1');
```

Your regular expression should take _large into account

```
var str1 = "Responsive_Course_2_2.png";
var str2 = "Responsive_Course_2_2_large.png";

var re = /(_large)?(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i;
console.log( str1.replace(re, '_large$2') );
console.log( str2.replace(re, '_large$2') );
```

Comment: I'm also setting the ImageSize to large, I was thinking that the If would then check the size and skip if its set to ImageSize != large.

Comment: That would work too, but don't you need to remove it when you go back and the image would be standard?

Comment: yeah if the screen is then made smaller the _large.png would be replaced with _standard.png

Comment: So the regex should be `/(_large|_standard)?(\.[\w\d_]+)$/i;`

Comment: I'm sorry would there be away to simply replace the _standard with _large or _xlarge?

Answer (score 0):

There's also the **background-size** css property. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but it sounds like it might be applicable.

```
#PageContentRow
{
  background-size: 100%; /* Scales background to #PageContentRow's width */
}
```